# Device specific resource management in cache manifest

Tags: html, html5-audio, cache-manifest, html5-appcache

Is there a way to target certain resources in the cache per device.

Im working on an offline html5 audio player. Obviously I have to specify filetypes such as Mp3 for use with webkit and Vorbis for firefox etc as per the HTML5 spec. However for use on mobile devices like the iPhone for example I only want to get the files needed to play in this case mp3. Is there a way for me to tell browsers to cache specific files or do they have to add all the resources no matter what. Thus eliminating the burden of the user having to cache more files needed and exceeding restrictions (I'm aware that in mobile safari only 10MB can be cached.)

Heres my manifest.

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:

index.html
master.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
style.css
buttons.png
coldplay.jpg
/player/tunes/waterfall-audio.m4a
/player/tunes/waterfall-audio.oga
```

So obviously in firefox I only need to cache the oga and webkit the mp3. 
Any insights would be great!

Comment: 10Mb max? Jeez, that's nothing if you need to store media.. What's the max cache size on Webkit?

Comment: I believe webkit is unlimited on win and osx

Answer (score 1):

What about using

```
/player/tunes/getDeviceAudio.php/waterfall-audio.audio
```

instead of

```
/player/tunes/waterfall-audio.m4a
```

And the PHP code (you can implement for another language)

```php
<?php
// replace the name
$filename = preg_replace('/.audio$/iu', '', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']); // waterfall-audio
$ext = '';
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) {
    default:
    case 'a user agent string': $ext = '.oga'; break;
    case 'another user agent string': $ext = '.m4a'; break; 
}
$filepath = "/path/to/audio/" . $filename.$ext;

echo file_get_contents($filepath);
```

The browser will think, it is a file to cache and will cache for the exact device. And each device will cache the correct file that its userAgent supports.

Answer (score 0):

or you generate the manifest dynamically and change the content according to the resolved user-agent.